# element not visible during animation

Tags: css, animation, 3d, css-animations

**Introduction**

I'd really appreciate it if someone could let me know what I'm doing wrong here. I'm a first-timer CSS user and I'm really stumped. I'd be very grateful if someone could help.

As a gift, I'll link to a game I made in defold: teeeth.itch.io/bikiniverse (html5, won't work on phones). Many thanks in advance.

-

**Objective:**

Create a 3D book-opening animation. Should work on as many browsers as possible.

-

**The problem:**

The front cover element becomes invisible during the animation after passing 180 degrees. Once the animation is finished, it becomes visible again (if you run the code below, the problem should be immediately clear).

If there's anything I've missed that would make it compatible with earlier browsers, I would appreciate that.

-

```
  <!DOCTYPE html><html>


    <head>
    <style>
    .flip-card {    
      -ms-transform: translate(20px, 0px) rotate(-3deg); /* IE 9 */
      -webkit-transform: translate(20px, 0px) rotate(-3deg); 
      -webkit-perspective: 1000px; /* Safari 4-8 */
      -webkit-perspective-origin: bottom; /* Safari 4-8 */
      perspective-origin: bottom;
      transform: translate(20px, 0px) rotate(-3deg);
      background-color: transparent;
      width: 150px;
      height: 100px;
      perspective: 1000px;
      text-align: right;

    }
    .flip-card-inner {
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;   
    transition: transform 3s;
    -webkit-animation-name: opener; 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s; 
    animation-name: opener;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1; 
    }

    .flip-card-inner {
      position: relative;
      top: -140px;
      right: 0px;
      text-align: center;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;   
    }

    .flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
      backface-visibility: hidden;
    }

    .flip-card-front { 
      position: absolute;
      right: -195px;
      color: black;
      z-index: 2;
      top: -214px;
    }
    .flip-card-back {
      position: absolute;
      right: -155px;
      top: -184px;
      transform: rotateY(180deg); 
      z-index: 0;
      width: 350px;
      height: 250px;
    }
    /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    @-webkit-keyframes opener {
      0%   {transform:rotateY(0deg)}
      100% {transform:rotateY(-100deg)}
    }
    /* Standard syntax */
    @keyframes opener {
      0%   {transform:rotateY(0deg)}
      100% {transform:rotateY(-100deg)}
    }

    </style>

    </head>

    <body>

    <div class="flip-card">
    <svg width="290" height="350">

    <rect x="70" y="30" rx="3" ry="3" width="220" height="310"style="fill:#ff5151"/>

    <rect x="283" y="40" rx="3" ry="3" width="1" height="294" style="fill:beige" />
    <rect x="282" y="40" rx="3" ry="3" width="1" height="294" style="fill:grey" />
    <rect x="281" y="40" rx="3" ry="3" width="1" height="293" style="fill:beige" />
    <rect x="280" y="40" rx="3" ry="3" width="1" height="293" style="fill:grey" />
    <rect x="279" y="40" rx="3" ry="3" width="1" height="292" style="fill:beige" />
    <rect x="278" y="40" rx="3" ry="3" width="1" height="292" style="fill:grey" />
    <rect x="277" y="40" rx="3" ry="3" width="1" height="291" style="fill:beige" />
    <rect x="276" y="40" rx="3" ry="3" width="1" height="291" style="fill:grey" />

    <rect x="75" y="40" rx="3" ry="3" width="201" height="290" style="fill:#FFFFF0" />


    <text x="81" y="75" font-size="17">196: </text>
    <text x="81" y="125" font-size="17">You have a magic envelope</text>
    <text x="81" y="143" font-size="17">which, when opened, says</text>
    <text x="81" y="162" font-size="17">the date of your death. </text>
    <text x="81" y="176" font-size="17"></text>
    <text x="81" y="194" font-size="17">Do you open the envelope? </text>



    <rect x="75" y="329" rx="3" ry="3" width="205" height="1" style="fill:grey" />
    <rect x="75" y="330" rx="3" ry="3" width="206" height="1" style="fill:beige" />
    <rect x="75" y="331" rx="3" ry="3" width="207" height="1" style="fill:grey" />
    <rect x="75" y="332" rx="3" ry="3" width="208" height="1" style="fill:beige" />
    <rect x="75" y="333" rx="3" ry="3" width="209" height="1" style="fill:grey" />

    </svg>


    <div class="flip-card-inner" id="frontcover">
    <div class="flip-card-front" >
    <svg width="370" height="350"><rect x=99 y=30 rx="3" ry="3" width="220" height="310" style="fill:#ff5151"/><text x="120" y="130"  font-family="Times New Roman" font-size="40" style="fill:#222222" font-style="italic">Malas </text><text x="120" y="165"  font-style="italic"  font-family="Times New Roman" style="fill:#222222" font-size="40">Decisiones </text></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
    <svg width="370" height="350">




    <rect x="00" y="0" rx="3" ry="3" width="220" height="310" style="fill:#ff5151"/>


    <rect x="19" y="10" rx="3" ry="3" width="2" height="287" style="fill:beige" />
    <rect x="21" y="11" rx="3" ry="3" width="2" height="288" style="fill:grey" />
    <rect x="23" y="12" rx="3" ry="3" width="2" height="289" style="fill:beige" />
    <rect x="25" y="13" rx="3" ry="3" width="2" height="290" style="fill:grey" />
    <rect x="27" y="14" rx="3" ry="3" width="2" height="291" style="fill:beige" />
    <rect x="29" y="15" rx="3" ry="3" width="2" height="292" style="fill:grey" />


    <rect x="30" y="299" rx="3" ry="3" width="201" height="2" style="fill:grey" />
    <rect x="29" y="300" rx="3" ry="3" width="202" height="2" style="fill:beige" />
    <rect x="28" y="301" rx="3" ry="3" width="203" height="2" style="fill:grey" />
    <rect x="27" y="302" rx="3" ry="3" width="204" height="2" style="fill:beige" />
    <rect x="26" y="303" rx="3" ry="3" width="205" height="2" style="fill:grey" />
    <rect x="25" y="304" rx="3" ry="3" width="206" height="1" style="fill:beige" />
    <rect x="24" y="10" rx="3" ry="3" width="207" height="289" style="fill:#FFFFE0" />



    </svg>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>




    <script>
    {
        document.getElementById(id="frontcover").style.WebkitBackfaceVisibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById(id="frontcover").style.backfaceVisibility = "hidden";
     }
    </script>



    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Could you clarify in what browsers should it work? I commented js code, there were errors. It seems to be working now.
 

https://jsfiddle.net/Lxyu6vmr/

Comment: Many thanks for your kind work Sabuja. I was able to understand your corrections and the animation now works well in all the browsers I have tried it in.